# Import large data from JSON file to MYSQL database using Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sequelize.js

I am trying to import data from JSON file to mysql database using **Sequelize**. I have written the following javascript code to achieve the same. Though it is working for the small data set but when I ran it for large file (containing millions of records) it does not work and the errors I see like.

1. javascript heap out of memory then I ran with this **node --max-old-space-size=4096 importRecords.js** then I got 2nd error
2. Unhandled rejection SequelizeConnectionAcquireTimeoutError: Operation timeout
   at pool.acquire.catch.error (F:\demo-sequelize\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\abstract\connection-manager.js:282:52)

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var JM = require('json-mapper');
const fs = require('fs');

var sequelize = new Sequelize('testdb', 'root', 'root', {
    dialect : 'mysql',
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      idle: 10000
    },
});

var Profile = sequelize.define('profile', {
  firstName: Sequelize.STRING,
  lastName: Sequelize.STRING,
  email: Sequelize.STRING
});

let rawdata = fs.readFileSync('largeData.json');
let input = JSON.parse(rawdata);

for(let customer of input){
  //console.log(customer.email);

  Profile.sync({force: true}).then(function () {
    // Table created
    return Profile.create({
      firstName: customer.firstName,
      lastName: customer.lastName,
      email: customer.email
    });
  });

}
```

Can anyone suggest how can I achieve this with

**1. minimum time may be using asynchronous execution. 

 2. In optimal way by minimizing sequelize logging while execution**

Answer (score 2):

I don't think reading this big file synchronously in memory is a good idea. Streaming is a better option in these kind of scenarios. There are many packages available which can do this kind of job. I will give an example for one of them.

`stream-json` (https://github.com/uhop/stream-json) - https://github.com/uhop/stream-json/wiki/StreamArray

```
const fs = require("fs");
const StreamArray = require('stream-json/streamers/StreamArray');

async function insertRec(row) {
  console.log(row);
  // code to insert the record
}

async function process() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream('path to json having array')
      .pipe(StreamArray.withParser())
      .on("data", async row => {
        await insertRec(row);
      })
      .on("error", err => {
        reject(err);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        console.log("CSV file successfully processed");
        resolve();
      });
  });
}

process();
```

this assumes you have a json in this format:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "field": 2
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "field": 5
  }
]
```

THis will give you an idea on how to integrate with your existing solution.

Comment: Thank you Ashish for reply, I tried this and I was still getting the heap out of memory issue then I ran it using **node --max-old-space-size=4096 importRecords.js** . but this helped in reading file (took less time to read)

Comment: It shouldn’t happen. How big is your file?

Comment: File size is about 290 MB

Comment: would it be possible for you to put the code on github so I can have a look as 290 MB is nothing. There must be something else which is causing this issue